# not able to get correct server name for connection string from Xamarin forms to my Google MySQL database

Tags: mysql, xamarin, connection

I have tried using connection name "genial-analyzer-306420:us-central1:cvmstrain" to no avail.
I tried using the public IP address "34.72.190.253" to no avail
i got the above connection name and public Ip address from my SQL database details

Comment: generally speaking it is a terrible, horrible, bad idea to connect directly to a db server from a mobile device

Comment: usually you use assh connection to tunnel to your server, see the documentation of your provider